# Installing NPM Package do not work inside Vagrant Ubuntu 18.04 LTS box

Tags: vagrant, npm

I am trying to install *nodemon* from *npm* inside my vagrant Ubuntu 18.04 LTS box using this command *npm install --save-dev nodemon* but i got error related to cannot find the file, i suspect that this is about the *symlink* about my shared folder that is why i tried to use flag *--no-bin-links* but i still got error.

## Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "base"
  
    config.vm.define "bionic_node_deno_v1" do |bionic_node_deno_v1|
      bionic_node_deno_v1.vm.hostname = "192.168.22.33"
      bionic_node_deno_v1.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"
      bionic_node_deno_v1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.22.33"
      bionic_node_deno_v1.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |bionicv|
        bionicv.memory = 4096
        bionicv.cpus = 4
      end
      bionic_node_deno_v1.vm.synced_folder "~/Documents/vagrant-sync-folder/node-deno-version-1-sf","/home/vagrant/Code"
    end

    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8085, host: 8787, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  
  end
```

## The Error

*Path that have error: /home/vagrant/Code* 
*Path that have no error: /home/vagrant/*

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/Code/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/has-flag/package.json.2851319490
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/Code/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/has-flag/package.json.2851319490'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2020-08-23T07_33_33_057Z-debug.log
```